# Visual Studio 2015 image editor - set transparent background 1 pixel

Tags: visual-studio-2015, image-editor

I'm trying to change an existing image to have a transparent background. According to the documentation, I should be a RGBA image and I should use the eraser tool to draw in the transparent background. This works, however the eraser tool is 5 pixels wide, which means I can erase small areas.

How do I change the eraser to 1 pixel wide?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using selection tool to mask out the area first.